# Stop jQuery parenting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I simply have some html code that works fine but when I add the jQuery UI library, it also adds its own classes to my original element classes.

However, this is not a problem but it also parents some elements meaning that it adds a div parent to those (some) elements.

This prevents the css rules of those elements from taking effect and also requires to rewrite the entire code to include the added jquery classes and parent element tags.

Am using absolute css target paths to style these elements like so...

```
div#searchAPI>div.a>input{
    font-size:18px !important;
    color: #585858;
    padding:0 60px 0 50px;
    border:0  !important;
    outline: none !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: red;
}
```

And the target element would be....

```
<div id="searchAPI">
    <div class="a">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

But when the jQuery UI lib is added, it adds it own custom parent to the `input` tag element like...

```
<div id="searchAPI">
    <div class="a">
        <div class="ui-textinput ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-textinput-text ui-body-inherit">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any sugguestions to how I can get rid of the extra parenting effect  are greatly appreciated, thanks...

Comment: Why don't you just use a less-specific selector like `div#searchAPI>div.a input`, which will target any level `<input>` that's inside of the `<a>`?

Comment: Hmm. Why not simply replace the `>` with spaces?